# Invalid font size in DataGridView on Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, windows-10, size

I develops an application via `Visual Studio` on `Windows 7`. The app bases on `WinForms` and has `DataGridView`. I want to change default font size for rows. I set `DefaultCellStyle` and `DataGridViewCellStyle` with `9pt` of `Microsoft Sans Serif` with help GUI constructor by `Visual Studio`.

When app runs on `Windows 7`, I see that font size was changed. But on `Windows 10`, size always default. How to fix it? What's problem?

Comment: What does `with help GUI constructor` mean? The Form's Designer? Change the Font to `Segoe UI` and try again. In any case, use a Font that supports the characters of the Local language. You might have Russian as locale. If the Font you have chosen doesn't support the local language, the System picks a Font surrogate.

Comment: @Jimi I don't know what it's called. According to keywords, your `Form's Designer` is also suitable. Both PC with the same local by language.

Comment: As already mentioned, try to set, explicitly, the Font to somethiing else. `Microsoft Sans Serif` does support Russian, but setting the Font explicitly is another thing. Set it to all configurations, including, for example, `RowDefaultCellStyle` and `RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle`